# Flex giving "fatal scanner internal error--end of buffer missed"

Tags: c, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

I am trying to use flex against a buffer that keeps getting filled and refilled.

I have multiple threads working with their own independent copies of the buffer.

In psuedo it looks something like this in my main program:

```
while(forever)
{
-fill buffer buf-
buf[length+1] = '\0';
buf[length+2] = '\0';
yy_scan_bytes(&buf, length+2);
yylex();
}
```

where multiple threads are running that loop, and all own their copy of buf.

I have a rule in my lex file that looks like this:

```
<<EOF>> {yyterminate(); yy_delete_buffer(YY_CURRENT_BUFFER);}
```

in an attempt to clean up after the buffer has run.

I am not sure if I am doing this right as this is my first attempt at using a flex scanner  in conjunction wtih another program. Would I be better off doing all the buffer handling from within flex, and linking it with an extern declaration in my main program?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that flex's default scanner is not reentrant -- it stores a bunch of info (including the current buffer to read from) in global variables, so if you try to have multiple threads scanning stuff at the same time, they'll step all over each other.

You need to use `%option reentrant` to create a reentrant scanner, and then create a separate `yyscan_t` for each thread to use, which you initialize with `yylex_init` and then pass as an extra argument to both `yylex` and `yy_scan_bytes`.

Also, `yyterminate` does an immediate return from the scanner, so your `yy_delete_buffer` call is never made.  You need to call it after the scanner returns:

```
yyscan_t local;
yylex_init(&local);
while(forever)
{
    -fill buffer buf-
    buf[length+1] = '\0';
    buf[length+2] = '\0';
    YY_BUUFER_STATE bs = yy_scan_bytes(&buf, length+2, local);
    yylex(local);
    yy_delete_buffer(bs, local);
}
```

Comment: In playing around with this some - does it make sense for me to make a function in the scanner that takes my buffer, and performs the `yylex_init`, etc in that function? Is that the only way I can get access to yyscan_t and other variables that it seemed i couldnt get in my main program?

Comment: @Derek: put all this code in the 3rd section of the .l file so it can access all the flex-defined types and declarations.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I am starting to try to fix this, and I am getting "unrecognized option" on the option. my flex is version 2.5.4 (pcbsd), was that option introduced later?

Comment: Updating did solve that reentrant option problem. just to clarify for anyone else - the buf you used as YY_BUFFER_STATE has a name conflict witht he buffer that is holding the data in your example

Comment: I will accept this answer because it answered the gist of what I was trying to do, but now i have a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957454/flex-reentrant-with-start-conditons