# Flex reentrant with start conditions

Tags: c, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

I am trying to make a reentrant scanner that relies on start conditions.

I was following along something similar to this guys question:

[Writing re-entrant lexer with Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634998/writing-re-entrant-lexer-with-flex)

And as the one poster mentioned, the scanner will work if you explicitly create the `yyscan_t` and pass it as an extra argument. However, I still get the `yyg undeclared` error message when using `BEGIN <sc>` , etc to manipulate the start condition.

Is this a bug? Should I explicity use the `yy_push_state` and `yy_pop_state` state functions instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when you use `%option reentrant` you can only use `BEGIN` and `YY_START` in the actions section of your lexer, and not in the code section.  Makes sense as manipulating the parser state requires access to the parser state, but `BEGIN` doesn't take any arguments, so there's no way to provide it.  Using `%option stack` and `yy_push`/`pop_state` seems like a reasonable workaround.